# Testing react-dropzone with cypress, `isDragActive` behaves differently from real usage

Tags: cypress, react-dropzone

I'm trying to test an application using react-dropzone. I'm using something like the following code:

```js
    const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop, noClick: true})

    return (
        <div
            {...getRootProps()}
            aria-label='file-upload-dropzone'
        >
            <input
                {...getInputProps()}
            />
            <div>
                {(isDragActive) ?
                    <span>Drop the files here...</span> :
                    <span>Drag and drop the files here</span>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

The problem here is that:

When trying to test with the following cypress test:

```js
            cy.get('[aria-label=file-upload-dropzone]')
                .selectFile(
                    {
                        contents: Cypress.Buffer.from('file contents'),
                        fileName: 'file.e37',
                        mimeType: 'text/plain',
                        lastModified: Date.now(),
                    },
                    {action: 'drag-drop'},
                )
            // the test fails here
            cy.contains('div', /Drag and drop the files here/).should('exist')
```

the UI is stuck with "Drop the files here...". The reason seems to be that `isDragActive` never goes back to false, after `cy.get(...).selectFile(...)` has been called.
This is different from when I test the exact same code from the browser - there, `isDragActive` is false AND "Drag and drop the files here" is displayed when I'm finished dragging the file.

Is there any way I can get the cypress test and a real user test to behave the same for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a hook, try adding `cy.wait(0)` or `setTimeout(() =>{},0)` before the failing line.

This would allow the hook to complete any background action - presuming the problem is that Cypress is hogging the thread

---

**Triggering "change" or "drop"**

The following seems to be a working sequence of events.

```js
cy.get('[aria-label=file-upload-dropzone]')
  .selectFile(
    {
        contents: Cypress.Buffer.from('file contents'),
        fileName: 'file.e37',
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        lastModified: Date.now(),
    },
    {action: 'drag-drop'},
  )

cy.contains('div', /Drop the files here.../)         // passes

cy.get('[aria-label=file-upload-dropzone]')
  .find('input').trigger('change', {force:true})     // without this trigger
                                                     // the next line fails

cy.contains('div', /Drag and drop the files here/)   // passes
```

I added a simple `onDrop()`

```js
const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
  console.log('acceptedFiles', acceptedFiles)
}, [])
```

and from this can see two console logs - the first has the file in `acceptedFiles`, the second has an empty array in `acceptedFiles`.

Comment: I tried this, and also tried with longer timeout/wait. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I ran your code into an app and it works. Of course, the `onDrop()` is missing - what do you have there?

Comment: Interesting! Even when `onDrop()` is just an empty function, this still don't work in my test. The piece of code I posted is deep inside an app, so I would then expect the problem to be related to something else in my DOM. I'll try to strip it down and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it "works" for me - so doing a bit more testing. I was expecting an error message on the last line, but it passes and now I think it does so before the drop action modifies the text.

Comment: If I add `cy.contains('div', /Drop the files here.../)` before `cy.contains('div', /Drag and drop the files here/)` I can make it fail.

Comment: I tried rendering the code above in the top level of React node (i.e. stripping away anything else), and the problem still persist. Also, by opening the cypress app, I can see that it's stuck with `Drop the files here...`.

Comment: What is also strange is that I can see that the `onDrop` callback is fired (by adding a console.log), so it definitely registers the drop somehow, it's just that the `isDragActive` is not properly reset to `false`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248851/discussion-between-simen-andresen-and-testerdick).

Answer (score 0):

Using a `change` event, as suggested by @TesterDick, produced other errors since the file input is looking for a file object on change. I think a more straightforward approach is to use `dragleave`.

Given the code provided, this should work:

```
cy.get('aria-label["file-upload-dropzone"]').trigger('dragleave')
```

You can use any selector on the root of your dropzone.